# How to process a large file with 30M entries?

Tags: r, large-files, outliers, large-data

First part of my question is, is there a faster way of calculation Standard deviation than

```
mySD = apply(myData,1,sd)
```

Second part of the question is how to remove outliers (3 SD away from the mean of each line) and recalculate the SD for each line.

Third part of the question is once i calculate the SD of each line, how to pick up the ones that are over certain threshold (as an example 0.05)?

My matrix has 30 millions roaw and 50 columns.

If there is a faster way than R (e.g., perl or matlab) i am also happy to try it.

...

I have a matrix with 30 million rows and 50 columns. For each line, I would like to remove the outliers and calculate the standard deviation (SD). So I will have 30 million SD. 
Then I would like to pick up those lines with the highest SD (top %5).

I tried R, but even loading the data into R is taking huge amount of time. I even saved the data as *RData. but still to slow and too much time consuming.

Is there a faster way of doing these things? either in r or perl or matlab?

Comment: "Faster way" doesn't mean much when we don't know what your way was or how fast it was....

Comment: @flodel In this case outliers will be 3SD away from the mean of each line.

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts to your question, efficient calculation and processing large data.

### Efficient calculation

Suppose you had a more manageable data set `m` with 5% of 30 million rows and 50 columns (this takes about 30% of my 8Gb; running out of memory would make everything run slowly so you'll need to let us know about this type of information).

```
nrow <- .05 * 30000000
ncol <- 50
m <- matrix(rnorm(nrow * ncol), nrow)
```

Maybe you'd write a function `clean` that efficiently removed the outliers on a per-row basis; it likely uses another function that efficiently calculates row-wise standard deviations

```
rowSD <- function(m) {
    ## efficiently calculate row-wise SD
    ## naive: apply(m, 1, sd, na.rm=TRUE)
    ## update via @BenBolker / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046820/change-row-values-to-zero-if-less-than-row-standard-deviation
    sqrt(rowSums((m - rowMeans(m, na.rm=TRUE))^2, na.rm=TRUE) / (ncol(m)-1))
}

clean <- function(m) {
    ## efficiently implement your strategy for identifying outliers
    m[abs(m - rowMeans(m)) > 3 * rowSD(m)] <- NA  # fast enough
    m
}
```

For the matrix `m` the naive implementation of `rowSD(m)` took about 56s, whereas the update from @BenBolker takes about 1.4 seconds; `clean(sd)` takes about 5s. Both make multiple copies of and passes through the data, so far from ideal.

### Large data

Think about processing your data in chunks of size `nrow`. If you'd cleaned two chunks `m1`, `m2` you could combine them and keep the top values with

```
sd <- c(rowSD(m1), rowSD(m2))
## if sorted, sd[idx] would be the value that separate high and low
idx <- nrow(result) + nrow(m) - nrow 
keep <- sd > sort.int(sd, partial=idx)[idx]  # index correct, or off-by-one?
## replace smallest in m1 with largest in m2
m1[!head(keep, nrow(m1)),] <- m2[tail(keep, nrow(m2)),]
```

Since you're doing matrix operations, it sounds like your data are all numeric and `scan`, reading files in chunks, is the appropriate input.

```
conn <- file("myfile", "r")
result <- matrix(0, nrow, ncol)
while (length(x <- scan(con, nmax = nrow * ncol))) {
    m <- clean(matrix(x, nrow, ncol, byrow=TRUE))
    sd <- c(rowSD(result), rowSD(m))
    idx <- nrow(result) + nrow(m) - nrow
    keep <- sd > sort.int(sd, partial=idx)[idx]
    result[!head(keep, nrow),] <- m[tail(keep, nrow(m)),]
}
close(conn)
```

`result` is then the desired collection of cleaned rows with highest standard deviation.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046820/change-row-values-to-zero-if-less-than-row-standard-deviation :  `sdbyrow <- function(mat) sqrt(rowSums((mat-rowMeans(mat))^2)/(ncol(mat)-1) )` might speed up `rowSD` considerably ... on a 1e5 x 1e2 matrix the timings were 6.5 secs vs 1 second.

Comment: @MartinMorgan Thanks a lot, I am trying this now. I will try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @MartinMorgan , the first column are the text and it is the headers. How can i change scan() so that it nows it is the header?

Comment: you can use `skip=1` in `scan()` (this doesn't seem to be directly related to your question??) (I'm guessing you mean the first *row*?)

Comment: @BenBolker i am trying to do row wise calculations and each row has a header (The first column is headers). MartinMorgan suggested to use scan() to load the files faster. But scan() does not like that I have headers.

Comment: I figured that -- it's just that your question doesn't say anything about loading files. I think `scan(...,skip=1)` should work, although you will have to set your column names manually (with a bit more work you can use `readLines(...,n=1)` to read just the first line and `strsplit()` to extract the individual words)

Comment: I though skip =1 will skip the first line rather than first column. But i do not want to skip them as i will need the names later when i do the filtering. read.table() has 'row.names=1', I am looking for something similar.

Comment: @user1007742 `scan` takes argument `what`, if you had 1 column character and 50 numeric, you'd say `xx = scan("file", what=c("", rep(list(0), 50)))` and bind together dropping first col as `do.call(c, xx[-1])`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(bigmemory)
?read.big.matrix
```

For starters. Then look at `biganalytics`, `bigtabulate`, `biglm`, etc.