# What is the fastest way to use `dplyr` to find the row-wise mean and variance of a large tibble?

Tags: r, optimization, dplyr

I am looking to generate a mean and variance value for every row in a numeric tibble. With my existing code, what I thought to be a very dplyr appropriate solution, it takes a number of hours to complete for 50,000 rows of about 35 columns.

Is there a way to speed up this operation using *only* dplyr? I know apply and purrr are options, but I am mostly curious if there is something about dplyr I'm overlooking when performing a large series of calculations like this.

Reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vroom)
gen_tbl(50000, cols = 40, 
        col_types = paste0(rep("d", 40), collapse = "")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(c_across()),
         var = var(c_across()))
```

My suspicion lies with `rowwise()` but I am interested if there is a more nuanced way to solving this with dplyr or if it is just not a problem dplyr is good at.

Comment: Maybe work with a matrix and use `?rowMeans` and `rowSD` as per this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/29581842/8583393
(sidenote: `rowMeans` will convert to a matrix anyhow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the processing time for the rowwise approach explodes quadratically:

[image]

Pivoting longer makes the calculation about 300x faster. For 50k rows, the code below took 1.2 seconds, compared to 372 seconds for the `rowwise` approach.

```
df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-row) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(value),
            var = var(value)) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

Comment: Wow what a steep curve! Definitely like this solution though, I had a suspicion the shape could be better. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you can get a row-wise variance function like `matrixStats::rowVars()` you can do this. I'm not sure why `c_across()` doesn't do it but `across()` seems to work. I got it from [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4544)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(vroom)

gen_tbl(
  rows = 50000, 
  cols = 40, 
  col_types = paste0(rep("d", 40), collapse = "")
) %>%
  mutate(
    mean = rowMeans(across(everything())),
    # var = rowVars(across(everything())),
    .before = everything()
  )

# A tibble: 50,000 x 41
#    mean     X1     X2   
#    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  
# 1  0.199   -0.715 -1.64   
# 2 -0.212   -0.983 -1.38   
# 3  0.126   -0.135  0.263
```