# TIBCO Spotfire Standard Deviation

Tags: database, visualization, spotfire

I have a data frame that has Percentages

Column1,Column2,Column3

5%,4%,3%

1%,2%,10%

I want to create an aggregated column, which calculates the standard deviation for each row of data (in my case, the standard deviation between 5%,4% and 3%, etc) using the stdev function on Spotfire. I have tried the formula input of :

StdDev([Column1],[Column2],[Column3])

This does not work. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That function is a column aggregation, meaning it will calculate some value over an entire column. You can create a calculated column with the formula for standard deviation. Another option would be to use TERR. See this question's top answer for how you do this in R: [Calculating standard deviation of each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861734/calculating-standard-deviation-of-each-row)